# Valor de DropDownLIst a objeto

Tags: c#

Hola comunidad un gusto soy jeff, nuevo en esta comunidad tengo una consulta:
tengo un dropdownlist que lo cargo con un enum y luego quiero crear un objeto

```
  Particular c = new Particular(documentoparticular, TipoDelCliente, nombreparticular, apellidoparticular, telefonoparticular, AnoClienteparticular, PaisDelCliente);
```

donde TipoDelCliente quiero pasarle el valor del DropDownList1 al objeto
como se hace?

```
Particular c = new Particular(documentoparticular,Cliente.EnumTipoCliente.Particular, nombreparticular, apellidoparticular, telefonoparticular, AnoClienteparticular, PaisDelCliente);
```

si lo hago de la siguiente manera funciona:
**Cliente.EnumTipoCliente.Particular**
se puede hacer que la opcion del drop down list la envie en el constructor?

```
  public Particular(string documento,EnumTipoCliente tipo , string nombre, string apellido, string untelefono, int unAnoIngreso,EnumPais pais)
    {
        this.Documento = documento;
        this.Tipo = tipo;
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Apellido = apellido;
        this.Telefono = untelefono;
        this.AnoIngreso = unAnoIngreso;
        this.pais = pais;
    }
```

Comment: Como cargas los elementos al DropDown List, es una cadena o un objeto?

Comment: es un enum tengo los datos , y hago in bind y data source

Comment: te funciono la respuesta que publique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intenta esto:

```
        Particular c = new Particular(documentoparticular, (EnumTipoCliente)dropdownlist1.SelectedValue, nombreparticular, apellidoparticular, telefonoparticular, AnoClienteparticular, PaisDelCliente);
```

el dropdownlist tendria que contener una propiedad que devuelva el valor seleccionado, intenta convertirlo al tipo de la enumeracion y pasarlo como argumento.

Comment: 20 años mas tarde, gracias.